# Jenkins on AWS: No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have just set up Jenkins (v2.69) on an AWS EC2 instance and I am accessing it through a web browser (Chrome).

However, when reaching the 'Create First Admin User' page, when I click save and finish I am hit with the following issue.

[No valid crumb was included in the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KXBL.png)

And also receive this from the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (No valid crumb was included in the request)
```

Is there something I am missing or have not set up?

I've been following [this tutorial](https://d0.awsstatic.com/Projects/P5505030/aws-project_Jenkins-build-server.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps to avoid the error:

1. change to Jenkins user by using the following command

   ```
   su – Jenkins –s /bin/bash
   ```
2. go to the config.xml and comment out the crumbIssuer from 
   `/var/lib/Jenkins/config.xml`:

[image: comment out]